# AdMob mediation message No fill from ad server

Tags: android, admob, adsense, adview

Hi I am working with AdMob in my app.

The following method used to set unit Id and set TestDevice.

```
public static void getInterstitialAdInstace(final Context mContext) {
    // Create the interstitial.
    interstitialView = new InterstitialAd(mContext);
    interstitialView.setAdUnitId(mContext.getResources().getString(
            R.string.GoogleAdMob_interAdUnitId));
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(
            AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();

    interstitialView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {


        }

    });

    // Begin loading your interstitial.
    interstitialView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

The following method used to show the interstitial ad.

```
public static void displayInterstitial() {

            if (interstitialView != null) {
        if (interstitialView.isLoaded()) {
            interstitialView.show();
        }
    }
}
```

We successfully uploaded the app into play store. But after few months we are getting zero impressions. We checked with code. The log-cat shows the following errors.

```
No fill from ad server.
No fill from any mediation ad networks.
```

I explored some. One of the among them is [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854789/admob-interstitial-ad-wont-display)

What should I do? Need to create any new AdUnitId? or anything need to do?

Comment: yes. you should use the solution in the link that you posted.

Comment: check your adsense/admob account, it might be that you have a problem with google...

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what ad networks you are using in your mediation flow.

You need to :

- Have several ad networks in your mediation config
- Have the ad network libraries and adapters for those libraries in your app
- Ensure you have at least a reasonable amount of traffic through your app.